# Torsion Chern class?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

1. Can somebody give an example of a complex manifold whose first Chern class is a torsion class? In general it seems that Chern classes may have torsion part as well as free part. However when using Chern-Weil theory computing in terms of de Rham cohomology we loose the torsion part.
2. Is there an example which has both free and torsion part?
3. Is there a Kähler manifold whose Chern classes involving torsion? Using the Kähler form to compute the first Chern class may result in losing the torsion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On a complex manifold $X$  the exponential sequence of sheaves of abelian groups $$0 \to \mathbb Z \to\mathcal O \stackrel {exp (2i\pi \cdot)}{\to}\mathcal O^*\to 0$$ yields a long exact sequence in cohomology containing the fragment $$\cdots \to H^1(X,\mathcal O)  \to  H^1(X,\mathcal O^*) \stackrel {c_1}{\to }  H^2(X,\mathbb Z)    \to    H^2(X,\mathcal O) \to \cdots     $$  Now suppose $X$ is an [Enriques surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriques_surface): such a surface is projective algebraic and thus certainly Kähler. By definition, it satisfies $$H^1(X,\mathcal O) =H^2(X,\mathcal O)=0 $$ [in algebraic geometry slang: irregularity=geometric genus =0] 
 so that our fragment above reduces to the isomorphism $$  0\to  H^1(X,\mathcal O^*) \stackrel {c_1}{\to }   H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\to 0   $$
Finally, also by definition, the canonical bundle $\omega_X$ of an Enriques surface is non trivial but its square *is* trivial.
The isomorphism above then yields that $c_1(\omega_X)\neq 0$ but $2c_1(\omega_X)=0$ , and this gives the required example since $c_1(T_X)=-c_1(\omega _X)$ ( I assume that by "first Chern class of a manifold" you mean that of its tangent bundle).

Comment: For the second question, the blowup of an Enriques surface is an example where $c_1$ has non-trivial free and torsion parts.